# Creating a top 5 Leaderboard with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, leaderboard

Users on my site gain points everytime one of their followers clicks on a link they posted. Right now I am able to show a list of everyone by using,

```
@users = User.all

<table>
<tr>
 <th>User</th>
<th>Points</th>
</tr>
<% @users.sort_by{|u| u.clicks.size }.reverse.each do |u| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= u.name %></td>
    <td><%= u.clicks.size %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

How can I have the block go through all the users then only display the top 5? Using the break if method is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
@users.sort_by{|u| u.clicks.size }.reverse[0...5].each do |u|
```

Or do away with the reverse altogether by negating the `sort_by`:

```
@users.sort_by{|u| -u.clicks.size }[0...5].each do |u|
```

Or you can have the database do the sorting for you:

```
@users = Users.joins(:clicks).order("clicks.size DESC").limit(5)
```